# AJAX request unable to find WebMethod in code-behind file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an aspx file that, on page load, is supposed to use ajax to call a webmethod from my code-behind file that gets data from a MySql database to display on the page.  The problem is that when the page loads and the javascript function containing the ajax request is called, I get the following error:

Unknown web method PopulateUsersList.
Parameter name: methodName

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method PopulateUsersList.
Parameter name: methodName

Im not sure as to why this happens when I have other ajax requests that I use throughout the page and they all work just fine.  Here is the code for the function containing the ajax request:

```
function loadUsersList(active) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ManagerPopup.aspx/PopulateUsersList',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ active: active }),
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log('loading users list...');
        },
        success: function(result){
            $('#userListDiv').empty();
            $('#userListDiv').append(result.d);
            $('#userListTable').DataTable({
                "lengthChange": false,
                "pageLength": 13,
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
            });
            $('#userListTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get();

                var id = $.trim(tableData[0]);
                var email = $.trim(tableData[2]);
                var phone = $.trim(tableData[3]);
                var active = $.trim(tableData[4]);

                getUserSpecifics(id, email, phone, active);
            })
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            console.log('error loading user list');
            console.log(ex.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the webmethod that it is trying to reach:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string PopulateUsersList(bool active)
    {
        ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();
        Query query = new Query();
        StringBuilder userListHTML2 = new StringBuilder();
        string userListHTML = "" +
            "<table runat=\"server\" id=\"userListTable\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-hover\">" +
                "<thead>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<th>User ID</th>" +
                        "<th>Name</th>" +
                        "<th>E-Mail</th>" +
                        "<th>Phone</th>" +
                        "<th>IsActive</th>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
                "<tbody>";           
        switch (active)
        {
            case true:
                userList = query.GetUserList(true);
                break;
            case false:
                userList = query.GetUserList(false);
                break;
        }
        foreach (User user in userList)
        {
            userListHTML2.Append(string.Format(@"
            <tr>
                <td>{0}</td>
                <td>{1}</td>
                <td>{2}</td>
                <td>{3}</td>
                <td>{4}</td>
            </tr>", user.userID, user.displayName, user.email, user.phone, user.isActive));
        }
        string userListHTML3 = "" +
                "</tbody>" +
            "</table>";
        string finalHTML = userListHTML + userListHTML2 + userListHTML3;
        return finalHTML;
    }
```

**NOTE:** The HTML that is being returned from the WebMethod is making it to the page somehow even though it says that the method itself cannot be found.

I have already tried removing static from the WebMethod.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have  another web method in same aspx page that is working? Make sure the web method is not in a user control code-behind, but an aspx code-behind.

Comment: Also, in your JavaScript function just before ajax call put the following statement to make sure the method parameter value is a valid value : `alert('active = ' + active);`. If you are passing a value other that true or false then it will result in an invalid call, and then you can be sure that this invalid value is causing the problem.

Comment: @Sunil I do have other web methods that work in the same aspx page.  Also, when alerting the value of active, it shows it being true.

Comment: Try using `[WebMethod()]`instead of [WebMethod] and make sure to re-compile  before testing the page.

Comment: made the change, still getting the unknown web method error.

Comment: I think its a code caching issue. The web method is not part of compiled code due to caching. Try using `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]` in place of WebMethod. But make sure to clean your solution and then rebuild your solution after making above change. This might force the code cache to get your latest code.